# JNDI requires JDK?

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi

I try to configure Oracle datesource for Tomcat6 from SUSE Linux Enterprise Server. I add datasource to context.xml file:

```
   <Resource 
   name="jdbc/UCPPool"
   auth="Container"
   factory="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl"
   type="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource"
   description="Pas testing UCP Pool in Tomcat"
   connectionFactoryClassName="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
   minPoolSize="2"
   maxPoolSize="5"
   inactiveConnectionTimeout="20"
   user="scott"
   password="tiger"
   url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
        (HOST=beast.au.oracle.com)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=
        (SERVICE_NAME=linux11gr2)))"
   connectionPoolName="UCPPool"
   validateConnectionOnBorrow="true"
   sqlForValidateConnection="select 1 from DUAL" />
```

In my application in persistence.xml add non-jta-data-source property. But each time when I want to start application, tomcat throw this exception:

```
   Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/nameDB]
         at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:78)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2279)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1748)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:920)
    ... 28 more
   Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: This context must be accessed throught a java: URL
   org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
```

I tried the same configuration on OpenSuse and there it works. The only difference I found is that SLSE has installed JAVA SE form IBM and openSUSE use OpenJDK java as a defualt.

So JNDI require JDK or it is some bug in IBM java implmenetation?

Comment: In your resource definition, the name is `jdbc/UCPPool`, but when you look it up you ise `jdbc/nameDB`. Isn't that incorrect?

Comment: I just forget to change when I copy from stacktrace. But eache t ime I use the same name

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title, no, JNDI is part of the JRE. No JDK required.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Do you have any idea why this is not working?